# Getting MAX datetime event from multiple tables, and outputing a simple list of most recent events by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, greatest-n-per-group, lateral-join

I have a table:

[image: Main Table]

and multiple other tables - consider them purchases, in this example:

[image: Apples]

[image: Pears]

[image: Bananas]

And would like an output table to show the most recent purchase (NB that there may be multiple instances of a purchase within each table), by id from the main table:

[image: Output]

The id can be a customer number, for example.

I've tried using OUTER APPLY on each purchase table, getting the TOP 1 by datetime desc, then getting the max value from the OUTER APPLY tables, but I would not get the table name - eg. Apples, just the datetime.

Another idea was to UNION all of the purchase tables together in a join with the main table (by id), and pick out the top 1 datetime and a table name, but I don't think this would be very efficient for a lot of rows:

```
    SELECT MT.id, MT.gender, MT.age, 
        b.Name as LastPurchase, b.dt as LastPurchaseDateTime 
    FROM MainTable MT
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, Name, MAX(dt) FROM
    (
    SELECT id, 'Apples' as Name, ApplesDateTime as dt FROM ApplesTable
    UNION
    SELECT id, 'Pears' as Name, PearsDateTime as dt FROM PearsTable
    UNION
    SELECT id, 'Bananas' as Name, BananasDateTime as dt FROM BananasTable
    )a
    GROUP BY etc
    )b
```

Does anyone have a more sensible idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a lateral join:

```
select m.*, x.*
from maintable m
outer apply (
    select top (1) x.*
    from (
        select id, 'apples' as name, applesdatetime as dt from applestable
        union all select id, 'pears', pearsdatetime from pearstable
        union all select id, 'bananas', bananasdatetime from bananastable
    ) x
    where x.id = m.id
    order by dt desc
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `apply`:

```
SELECT MT.id, mt.gender, mt.age, p.*
FROM MainTable MT OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT p.name, p.dt
      FROM (SELECT id, 'Apples' as Name, ApplesDateTime as dt FROM ApplesTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, 'Pears' as Name, PearsDateTime as dt FROM PearsTable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, 'Bananas' as Name, BananasDateTime as dt FROM BananasTable
           ) p
       WHERE p.id = mt.id
       ORDER BY dt DESC
      ) p
```